# Silverlight errors in data formats on binding

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I'm trying to take care with every possible error when a property gets its value through a Binding (MVVM) like being out of a given range.

This is working perfect by using "ValidatesOnDataErrors" in the control I want to check.

The problem comes when I try to check if the given value is accepted by that property in the modelView.

For example, when I write "june" in a DateTimePicker control the binding is broken (the property is a DateTime) so it never gets its value and I can't control the errors the same way I do with the rest of rules.

How should I try this? Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was really simple!!

If you have a DateTime property binded to a textbox, it's enought to set "ValidatesOnExceptions=True" on Binding instruction from XAML.

If you just want to parse this by youself, you have to use ValidatesOnDataErrors=True and make a validation function to raise a message.